# Save data in related tables Symfony 4

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, symfony4

First of all, I apologize for my little knowledge of the sector, but I am new to Symfony and PHP.
I am doing a new project using Symfony 4 and the following problem arises.

I have two tables in my application, one for Contracting and another for Alerts.
They are related to each other through an intermediate table, since a contract can have several alerts at the same time.
I leave an image so you can see the relationship.

[image]

I already have all the entities created with their Setters and Getters and all the forms made and working, to add a new alert and a new contract and all the additional functionality.
My purpose is to program a function, so that in the intermediate table are stored the IDs of contracts and alerts and are related to each other so that later I can show a list of contracts with their respective alerts.

I can not create the logic to collect the contract ID and the ID of the alert and save it in the table that relates them and then shows it.

I do not know if I've explained myself correctly or if I say some nonsense, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please read the [Doctrine2 Many-to-Many docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)  carefully.
After proper relations configuration creating relations with `Doctrine` will be as easy as:

```
$contact->addAllert($alert);
```

With proper flushing if you don't have `cascade: persist` configured.

You don't have to take care about the joining table - `Doctrine2` will take care of it for you.